# Swap Windows and Linux hard drives

Tags: linux, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

Following situation: I have a laptop with a SSD and a HDD in it.

- Windows 8.1 is installed on the SSD
- The HDD holds a data partition

Some weeks ago is tried to work with Linux an installed it at the end of the data partition. So the new config is like this:

- Windows on the SSD
- Data at the beginning of the HDD, Linux at the end

Now I want to swap the drives without formatting or reinstalling neither Windows nor Linux, so that in the end Linux uses the full space of the SSD and the HDD hosts Windows at the beginning and a data partition at the end.

Has anyone a hint for me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. move the data partition to make space for the Windows partitions (boot and c:)
2. use dd to clone Windows partitions to the start of the HDD
3. format the SSD
4. use dd to clone Linux partitions (boot, /, swap) to the SSD
5. expand / so Linux uses all space on the SSD
6. delete Linux partition from the HDD, expand data partition to the end of the disk

You can do all of this from a Linux live disk using gparted and dd, but definitely make backups before you start.

Boot loaders will need to be fixed afterwards. Use this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure which windows partitions to clone with dd. Already tried to clone all the partitions on the SSD to the free space on the HDD, including efi partition. Grub recognized the new windows installation, but when choosing it in the bootloader, it automatically switched to boot the windows installation on the SSD, maybe because of the GPT or the BCD entries?!

Comment: I'd try to solve that by disconnecting the old Windows drive (SSD) and running the boot loader fix from the Windows install medium. bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd